# having trouble with import tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and it looks like `tensorflow.contrib` was removed in `tensorflow` when major version was bumped from 1 to 2. Try downgrading your tensorflow to latest v1 version:

```
pip install -U 'tensorflow<2'
```